# Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at ZAD1.vhd(7) near text ";"; expecting ":", or ","

Tags: vhdl, error

So basically I am doing the 7-input NAND gate and the syntax error keeps showing up (Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Router.vhd(39) near text "port"; expecting "(", or "'", or ".").

```
library IEEE;   
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;   
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;  
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;  
entity Seven_NAND is  
port (NAND_IN: in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)  
NAND_OUT; signal STD_LOGIC  
end Seven_NAND  

architecture behav_sig of Seven_NAND is  
signal odd : std_logic  
begin   
test_case: process (NAND_IN)  
   begin  
   odd <= '1' -- Default  
   case (NAND_IN) is  
       for index in 6 downto 0 loop  
           odd <= odd nand NAND_IN(index);  
       end loop;  
   end case  
end process test_case;  
NAND_OUT <= odd;  
end behav_sig;
```

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what is wrong. Fix your VHDL syntax in line 7!

Comment: I know error messages can be pretty useless sometimes, but this one is telling you exactly how to fix it!

Comment: Hint: it does not like your ';' in line 7. Also check your brackets. For every open bracket you should have a close one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not see the multitude of problems here with incomplete syntax? You are being careless with your code. I know you know what to type because you do not make the same mistakes all the time. Go read your code slowly line-by-line, or compare the similar parts of your code to each other.

I will point out the one unique mistake that points to lack of understanding rather than lack of care: look up what case statements are in VHDL. It seems like you have no idea what they actually do, let alone the syntax.

> >
>   library IEEE;
>    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
>   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
>   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
>   entity Seven_NAND is
>   port (NAND_IN: in **std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)**
>   **NAND_OUT**; **signal** **STD_LOGIC**
>   end **Seven_NAND**
>
> architecture behav_sig of Seven_NAND is
>   signal odd : **std_logic**
>   begin
>   test_case: process **(NAND_IN)**
>      begin
>      odd <= **'1'** -- Default
>      **case (NAND_IN) is**
>          for index in 6 downto 0 **loop**
>              odd <= odd nand NAND_IN(index);
>          end loop;
>      end **case**
>   end process test_case;
>   NAND_OUT <= odd;
>   end behav_sig;